# PHP on IIS 6 as ISAPI, which process isolation mode?

Tags: php, iis-6, fastcgi, isapi

We have IIS 6 server with many php applications. PHP 5.2 runs as ISAPI modul and IIS is set to IIS 5.0 Isolation Mode.

Now I want to switch to FastCGI and enable application pools, with needs to release IIS 5.0 Isolation Mode and use Worker Process Isolation Mode.

But I don't know, if it is safe to change. Server is production, so I better ask you for your experiences, before any big mistake (apps are not so critical, but one restart is enough).

Do you have any experiences with this setting? On what deppends, if application will bee working fine on second mode also?

Comment: I suggest you switch to IIS7 with FastCGI.  And as with any modifications to a production server, thoroughly test it first in a non-production environment.

Answer (score -1):

Switching large setups that are live is never an easy thing.

Because you ask if it's safe, I'd say, it's highly likely if you do the switch, you're not found enough to cope with problems and situations that can potentially occur which will make the process unsafe.

Take note that this is independent to the technical problems here, it's just the soft-skills. You can simulate the technical problems by cloning the live system and doing the switch on the clone so you know into which problems you will likely run.

My suggestion: Leave the system running until you *need* to switch. If there is a real need, there is a real will and there is budget to hire professionals that just do the job.

Comment: I understand that, but I was asking for some experiences. Thank you anyway.